Stumped trying to run Tensorflow using GPUs on WSL
I am trying to install and run Tensorflow to take advantage of GPUs on a Windows 11 machine by using WSL via Conda.
I've previously tried installing and running tensorflow without Conda. Here's my recollection of what happened there:
WSL without Conda

I install cuda. nvcc -V shows it's installed, build 11.5.r11.5
I create and activate a virtual environment.
I install tensorflow
Running the following code reports zero GPUs available. My PC definitely has a GPU.

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info as build

# Check if TensorFlow can access the GPU
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(physical_devices))


if physical_devices:
    print("TensorFlow GPU details:")
    for gpu in physical_devices:
        print(gpu)
else:
    print("No GPUs detected by TensorFlow.")
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())

print(build.build_info['cuda_version'])

In fairness I didn't expect this to work because I couldn't figure out how to install cuDNN on WSL. But I read that Conda could install cuDNN so I tried that way:
WSL with Conda to install Cuda and cuDNN
Anaconda Install on Linux docs
How to Install the Latest cuDNN with Conda: A Guide for Data Scientists

curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2024.02-1-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2024.02-1-Linux-x86_64.sh
it seems to be installed now. conda create --name cudnn_env python=3.8 makes a conda env.
conda activate cudnn_env
conda install -c conda-forge cudnn
run  python TfGpuTest.py and get:

2024-05-27 17:23:19.552732: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Num GPUs Available:  0
No GPUs detected by TensorFlow.
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TfGpuTest.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(build.build_info['cuda_version'])
KeyError: 'cuda_version'

edit: I was asked which tensorflow version I use. I don't know what it was before but it was an old one because I made the conda env using python 3.8. I made a new environment using python 3.12 and conda install tensorflow said:
(cudnn_env3) name@Castle:~$ conda install tensorflow
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides bleach 1.5.0 needed by tensorboard-1.6.0-py27hf484d3e_0

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.12.* , which can be installed;
└─ tensorflow is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ tensorflow [1.10.0|1.11.0|...|2.1.0] would require
   │  └─ python 2.7.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [1.10.0|1.9.0] would require
   │  └─ python 3.5.* , which conflicts with any installable versions 

# I cut out a bunch of stuff here

   ├─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.11.0|...|2.9.1] would require
   │  └─ python 3.9.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   └─ tensorflow 2.12.0 would require
      └─ python 3.11.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Notice that tensorflow 2.15 isn't available, isn't mentioned.
so i downgraded to 3.11.9 and conda install tensorflow now conda list tensorflow shows 2.12.0

What version of TF do you install? TF >= 2.15 is compatible with CUDA 12.

Which version of tensorflow are you using? Did you check that you're installing the right library version? Tensorflow 2.16 requires CUDA 12.3 and cuDNN 8.9.0 for example. If you're using mismatched version, TensorFlow will not find your GPU. See the whole list of tested working configurations

Updated OP to include tensorflow version. I can't figure out how to get cuda 12.3 plus TF >=2.15

Just use pytorch instead , which don't need setup WSL, even with latest which is cuda 12.4
you can use onnx to convert tensorflow model to pytorch and train it with pytorch gpu enable. Or simple just stick pytorch seem they have better support and more flexible than tensorflow.
you can ask LLM like copliot it can tell you how with sample code
